# why my cv2.imshow() stay on first frame when I used threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I need to play video files using cv2 with threading. It works for the first file properly but freezes on first frame of  the second file and stops there.. How can I fix it?

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2
files = [ 'video_1','video_2']
def player (video):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video+'.mp4')
    while cap.isOpened() :
        time = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
        fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        total_frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
        print(time, fps, total_frames)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
           cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
           if cv2.waitKey(33) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
               break
        else:
            break

for i in files :
   t1 = Thread (target = player , args = (i,))
   t1.start()
   t1.join()
```